# Compute the value of $M=\frac{2015!}{2002!\cdot13!}\;\bmod\;2017$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Recently, I have found this problem:

> Given that $2017$ is a prime number, compute the value of the following expression:
> $$M=\frac{2015!}{2002!\cdot13!}\;\bmod\;2017$$

I have tried two diffent ways:

-In Python I have written a small program to compute the result. Here's the code:

```
>>>def F(n):
   ...  if n==1:
   ...          return 1
   ...  else:
   ...          return n*F(n-1)
```

And:

```
>>>import sys
>>>sys.setrecurcionlimit(2020)
>>>M = F(2017)/(F(2002) * F(13)) % 2017
```

-In the second way, I have written all prime factors of $\{2015,2014,\cdots,2004,2003\}$ and then I have simplyfied the left side of the expression. I obtained:
$$M\;\bmod\;2017\equiv5\cdot7\cdot17\cdot19\cdot31\cdot41\cdot53\cdot59\cdot61\cdot67\cdot167\cdot223\cdot251\cdot401\cdot503\cdot2003\cdot2011\;\bmod\;2017$$ where all numers are primes. But how can we go on?

Comment: Isn't that last number supposed to be $2011$ - maybe just a typo? Interesting that the result is just $2003$ per https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Mod%5B2015%21%2F%282002%21+13%21%29%2C+2017%5D. So, all those other terms will Mod $2017$ to one, but maybe there is some slick way to do that.

Comment: I think Lucas theorem might be useful. Note that the term with factorials is simply 2015C13.

Comment: @Moo: yes, corrected. Sorry.

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem. It's the most effective way, I think.

Comment: Since Python 3.8 you can do `import math` followed by `print(math.comb(2015, 13) % 2017)` to get the result.

Comment: @richrow: so, I have to compute $\binom{2}{2}\cdot\binom{0}{0}\cdot\binom{1}{0}\cdot\binom{5}{2}\;\bmod\; 2017$?

Comment: @Matteo your application of lucas's theorem is wrong. I guess Lucas's theorem won't work here as $2015<2017$.

Comment: So, what can we do?

Comment: @ABCD, indeed, Lucas's theorem is useless here. Probably, it's better to use modular arithmetic.

Comment: Note that $M=\dbinom{2015}{13}$

Answer (score 11):

$$ (13!) M = \prod_{k=2003}^{2015} k \equiv \prod_{k=2003}^{2015} (k-2017) \pmod {2017}$$
Observe that:

$$ \prod_{k=2003}^{2015} (k-2017) = (-1)^{}\prod_{k=2003}^{2015} (2017 - k)= (-1)^{}\prod_{k=2}^{14} k= -(14!)$$
so we get
$$ M \equiv -14 \equiv {2003}\pmod {2017} $$

Answer (score 3):

Notice that if we let
$$ M :=\frac{2015!}{2002!\cdot13!} \mod 2017, \tag{1} $$
then by definition of binomial coefficients
$$ M \equiv \binom{ 2015}{ 13} \bmod 2017. \tag{2} $$
Now notice we are given that $2017$ is prime and
that $$ 2015 \equiv -2 \mod 2017. \tag{3} $$
If $\,p\,$ is a prime,$\,0 < n < p,\,$ and
$\,x \equiv y \mod p\,$ then
$\,\binom {x}{n} \equiv \binom{y}{n}\mod p\,$ so
$$ M \equiv \binom{ -2}{ 13} \bmod 2017. \tag{4} $$
Now we use $$ (-1)^n (n+1) = \binom{ -2}{ n} \tag{5} $$
and thus the final result is
$$ M = (-1)^{13}(13+1) = -14 \equiv 2003 \mod 2017. \tag{6}$$

Comment: Can you help me understand why $(-1)^n (n+1) = \binom{ -2}{ n} \tag{5}$?

Comment: @FormulaWriter Please refer to the Wikipedia article [Binomail coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalized_binomial_coefficients) section "Generalized binomial coefficients" where $\,z=-2.$

Comment: I see, it is simply a direct computation. Thank you. The fact that $2015 \equiv -2 \mod 2017 \tag{3}$ entails $M = \binom{ -2}{ 13} \bmod 2017 \tag{4}$ relies on the fact that $(13!)^{-1}$ makes sense in $\mathbb{Z}_{2017}$, doesn't it?

Comment: @FormulaWriter No, it doesn't. If $\,x\equiv y \mod m\,$ then $\,\binom{x}{n}\equiv \binom{y}{n} \mod m\,$ for any positive integer $\,n,m.$

Comment: $\binom {-2}{2}=3 \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$ but
$\binom {4}{2}=6 \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$. I think the problem is that $x \mapsto \binom {x}{n}$ is a polynomial function with rational (not integer) coefficients.

Comment: @FormulaWriter Thanks for that comment! I have used $2017$ is prime as you suggest.